# Java - Adding JButton to JApplet

Tags: java, jbutton

I am trying to add a JButton Array to my GridLayout but it seems not to be working.

Probably a rookie mistake -- what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Grid extends JApplet
{
    public JButton[] inv;
    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));
        int i = 0;
        while(i>20)
        {
            inv[i] = new JButton("Slot #" + i);
            add(inv[i]);
            System.out.println("Button " + i + " added.");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

PS - If you something that could be programmed in a better manner -- please fix it for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't create the array, read your text books on how to allocate entries for an array. The [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) tutorial has a section on using arrays.
2. Your loop is wrong. Is `i` ever greater than 20?

Comment: You're no help. But the way you're talking down to me makes me look like an idiot. Get some kindness in your heart.

Comment: Not only did I solve your immediate problem with the loop, I pointed out your next problem with the null array. I don't believe in spoon feeding answers, you need to learn to develop your own problem solving skills. Also, you need to learn to read tutorials (which is why I gave you the link) and the API.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to do was:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Grid extends JApplet
{
    public JButton[] inv = new JButton[20]; //Initlaized array
    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));
        int i = 0;
        while(i<20) //Used less than sign instead of ">"
        {
            inv[i] = new JButton("Slot #" + i);
            add(inv[i]);
            System.out.println("Button " + i + " added.");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```